# How can I get current taxonomy term id?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I need to get current taxonomy term id. I am using this code.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'property',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'property_category',
                  'field' => 'id',
                  'terms' => array( 84, 99, 98, 97, 92, 91, 95, 100, 87, 96, 94, 93 ),
                  'include_children' => false
            )
        )
    );
```

As you see in the 'terms' section I made an array of all the terms but I need like if current page term id is 98, I want to set the Id 98 only in the array.

Let me show you an example:
this url https://ayanaproperties.com/property-for-sale/london/ has term ID 98, the term is showing only 5 properties which is correct, but on the map section map is showing all the 220 properties. This is because in the above code I specified all the IDs in terms array.

All the IDs in array are using the same code thats why I need if else condition.

Please help me, How can i get this using if else condition?

Thanks,

Comment: I think you need to prepare the terms array based on term id . isn't it ?

Comment: show the code where your preparing the $args

Comment: @JYoThI I have put the php code in the js section of the pen, see it here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLNjww

Comment: whats that id `$_POST['propcateg_id']` why are u not using it in ur args query

Answer (score 3):

Please use below line which will return current term ID then you can pass that value in your array.

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
```

Comment: Have been reviewing dozens of SO threads on this, your snippet is great.